# problem in tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My problem :

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:currentIndex]] withRowAnimation:YES];  //passing argument 1 of indexSetWithindex makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

---

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
if (!self.editing) {


    if(indexPath.section%2!=0)
    {

        ConsultationCarteV *consultationCarteV = [[ConsultationCarteV alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConsultationCarteV" bundle:nil];
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [CartesManager sharedInstance].indexCarteCourante=indexPath.row ;
        [CartesManager sharedInstance].isEditable = NO ; 

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:consultationCarteV animated:YES];
        [consultationCarteV release];


    }
     else {

       currentIndex = indexPath.section +1 ; 
       [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:currentIndex]] withRowAnimation:YES];  //passing argument 1 of indexSetWithindex makes integer from pointer without a cast  


        }
}
```

Comment: Separate issue: The withRowAnimation parameter expects a UITableViewRowAnimation enum like UITableViewRowAnimationFade (not a bool).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`NSIndexSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) stores integers not `NSIndexPath`s. The only thing you need to pass to the index path is the unsigned integer of the section and not an NSIndexPath object.

> The NSIndexSet class represents an
>   immutable collection of unique
>   unsigned integers, known as indexes
>   because of the way they are used. This
>   collection is referred to as an index
>   set.

Your original code example will look like this

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentIndex];
[tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

As Anna Karenina points out in the comments withRowAnimation: is not looking for a `BOOL` but an `UITableViewRowAnimation`. Make sure you check the documentation or Jump to Definition (^⌘D) to check the type of arguments that are expected for the methods you call.