# Get selected column and row from NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview

I have a table with 2 columns. And for each column am populating data from an unique array which is contained in a dictionary. So now when I click on a row in second column, its not possible to extract data from the dictionary as I dont get Column selected, but only row.

```
[tableView selectedColumn] //returns -1
[tableView selectedRow] //returns 1, but I needed the column number as well so I could pick the array from dictionary.
```

How can I get the column selected ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in NSTableViewDelegate, you have a few options you can take advantage of.

Apple's most preferred one to use is:

["`tableView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:), which gives you the "proposed" selection range (i.e. something you can keep track of) as a NSIndexSet, but [it can be a bit tricky to understand how to extract NSIndexPaths from a NSIndexSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653033/problem-in-tableview).

Instead, you can also keep track of *both* the selected row and selected column by handling the delegate methods:

["`tableView:shouldSelectRow:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldSelectRow:)

and

["`tableView:shouldSelectTableColumn:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldSelectTableColumn:)

Comment: Am using a view based table view, so each cell will load data from a dictionary. I have removed headers from table view, so these delegates are not getting invoked. I have set `table setAllowsColumnSelection:YES` as well.

Comment: why do you think "`tableView:shouldSelectRow:`" and "`tableView:shouldSelectTableColumn:`" should only work for non-view tables?  I don't see that restriction in Apple's documentation.  Do any NSTableViewDelegate methods work for you, or did you forget to set your table view's delegate?

Comment: sorry that I didnt mention before, I have added table view programtically. Other delegates are working fine, but this one doesnt get invoked, so I thought column was not allowed to be selected and I added `setAllowColumnSelection:YES` to make it selectable but still these delegates wont get invoked.