# Selected Column Of NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying this solution also But It doesn’t solve my problem

[Get selected column and row from NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873180/get-selected-column-and-row-from-nstableview)

[Get selected row and column in view based nstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947408/get-selected-row-and-column-in-view-based-nstable)

How can I get the column selected ? 
what i get when i am using `selectedColumn` property of `NSTableView`

```
[tableView selectedColumn] //returns -1
[tableView selectedRow] //returns 1,
```

is there any way to get selected column

> Note: I want to get selected column  without creating subclass of
>   NSTableView class

Comment: What does it mean in Objective-C if an integer is -1?  That's basics.

Comment: @EI  -1 means  column is not selected

Comment: Apparently row 1 is selected. You can't select a row and a column at the same time.

Comment: then how can i get column number

Comment: Do you want the selected column or the column being edited?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, here is the link of my problem solved by Ken Thomases. I hope it could help you too!

[Click here to see the problem solved: How do I select column and row from a NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095592/how-do-i-select-column-and-row-from-a-nstableview)

[In objective-C I think it should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waDxP.png)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am using objective c and your code in swift and i dont know much about swift, please can you explain about columnForView(sender) method or its equivalent  in objective c

Comment: `[self.tableview rowForView:sender];` and the same with columns. I think should look like that, but i'm not an objective-c expert. (I added an image on my old answer)

Comment: @RafaFebrer you sir, are a lifesaver. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the column being edited:

```
id firstResponder = self.window.firstResponder;
if ([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSView class]])
    NSInteger column = [self.tableView columnForView:firstResponder];
```

Comment: Thank you For answer But I want selected column not column being edited.

Comment: The selected column is `[tableView selectedColumn]`.

Comment: `[tableView selectedColumn]` will gives -1.  so it does not solve my problem

Comment: Did you select a column?