# How do I select column and row from a NSTableView?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I am writing a NSTableView based view. And I try to use:
`let selectedRowNumber = tableViewMesos.selectedRow` and 
`let selectedColumnNumber = tableViewMesos.selectedColumn` to identify the textField that is in the cell View that I want to save into my array:

```
taulaDeConsumsMesos[selectedColumnNumber].filesConsum![selectedRowNumber] = sender.doubleValue
```

But a problem happens here, because the return value of `selectedColumnNumber` is -1 which is the value of non-selected Column for any row selected of any column.
But the `selectedRowNumber`returns the index of the row properly.

So the program crashes when finishing the edition of a textfield in a cell. Because the selectedColumnNumber is -1 out of the limits of the array. See the code below to identify where this happens exactly.

Could you help me? I lost too many hours on this..
I'm new on OSX programing I hope you could help me.

[The app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjfQF.png)

Here is the completed code:

```
class BalancGlobalViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewMesos: NSTableView!

let mesos = ColumnaDeConsumsMes() // contains an array of doubles called .filesConsum that represent the rows that I want to show
let consum = ColumnaDeConsumsMes()

var taulaDeConsumsMesos = [ColumnaDeConsumsMes]() // array of arrays that represent the columns with rows in it that will be the tableView data

func setUpMesos(){ // init table columns
    mesos.filesConsum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12, nil]
    consum.filesConsum = [100, 100, 100, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil , nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
    taulaDeConsumsMesos.append(mesos)
    taulaDeConsumsMesos.append(consum)
}

func setUpGradient(){
   ...not important here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpMesos()

    tableViewMesos.setDelegate(self)
    tableViewMesos.setDataSource(self)

    setUpGradient()

}

override func viewDidLayout() {
    super.viewDidLayout()

    setUpGradient()
}

@IBAction func alEditarUnTextFieldDeConsum(sender: NSTextField) { // this is the IBAction of the TextField of the Consum Column (see the image)

    let selectedRowNumber = tableViewMesos.selectedRow
    let selectedColumnNumber = tableViewMesos.selectedColumn

    print("SelectedRowNumber! =  \(selectedRowNumber)")
    print("SelectedColumnNumber! =  \(selectedColumnNumber)")
    // the selectedColumnNumber return always -1 except when clicking the header of the column, then return 0 or 1 depending on the column. But it should return 0 even when the user edit a row of the index 0 column !!!

    let numero = tableViewMesos.numberOfColumns
    print("numero de columnes: \(numero)") // returns 2

    if selectedRowNumber != -1 {      //-1 is returned when no row is selected in the TableView
        taulaDeConsumsMesos[selectedColumnNumber].filesConsum![selectedRowNumber] = sender.doubleValue  //try to save here the value edited by the user on my array of arrays of doubles 
//here the program crashes! selectedColumnNumber = -1

        print("Sender! =  \(sender.doubleValue)") // the sender returns the information correctly
        //print("SelectedRowNumber! =  \(selectedRowNumber)") // this works too!

        reloadTaula()
    }

}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    print("columna: \(tableViewMesos.selectedColumn)") 
    print("row: \(tableViewMesos.selectedRow)")
    print("tag: \(tableViewMesos.selectedTag())")
}
// the tableViewMesos.selectedColumn return always -1 except when clicking the header of the colum, then return 0 or 1 depending on the column. But i should return 0 even when I edit a row of the index 0 column !!!

func reloadTaula() {
    tableViewMesos.reloadData()
}


// MARK: - Datasource

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    if (tableView.identifier == "TaulaMesos") {
        return 13
    } 
}


// MARK: - Delegate

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    var valorCela: Double
    var cellIdentifier:String=""  

    if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
        if taulaDeConsumsMesos[0].filesConsum![row] == nil {
            return nil
        }else {
            valorCela = taulaDeConsumsMesos[0].filesConsum![row]!
            cellIdentifier = "MesCellID"
        }
    } else {
        if taulaDeConsumsMesos[1].filesConsum![row] == nil {
            return nil
        }else {
        valorCela = taulaDeConsumsMesos[1].filesConsum![row]!
        cellIdentifier = "ConsumCellID"
        }
    }
    if let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, owner: nil ) as? NSTableCellView {
        cell.textField?.doubleValue = valorCela
        return cell
    }
    return nil

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table views do not support selecting individual cells. Both styles of table view support selecting rows. Old-style `NSCell`-based table views support selecting columns, but modern view-based table views no longer support selecting columns. But it would never have been the case that both `selectedRow` and `selectedColumn` were valid at the same time.

From the [10.7 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#10_7TableView), where view-based table views were introduced:

> Note that the View Based TableView does not support column selection.

To get the row and column of the cell whose text field sent the action, you should use `tableViewMesos.rowForView(sender)` and `tableViewMesos.columnForView(sender)`. Note, especially, that there's nothing guaranteeing that the text field that's sending the action method is in a selected row. So, don't think of it as selected. It's just the one that's been manipulated by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken!